# Cells not removed from UITableView after endUpdates until reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm experiencing pretty mysterious glitch:
After `endUpdates` was called all removed updated cells becoming just hidden and new cell will created, without reusing existing ones.
Usually even `-tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` not called, but not always.

Result looks like this:

[image]

I have no any clue about reasons of this behavior and will appreciate any ideas how to debug and fix this.

Unfortunately, source code it pretty complex and I'm unable to extract something intergal. if you ask me about related code - i will copy it to there.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id item = [self.presenter.mediator itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *reuseIdentifier = [self.reuseIdentifierMatcher reuseIdentifierForItem:item];
    UITableViewCell<ViewItemProtocol>* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier
                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.item = item;
    return cell;
}


- (void)applyChangesSet:(TableChangesSet*)changes
{
    LOG_VALUE(@([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]));
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    for (TableChange *change in changes.changes)
    {
        [self applyChange:change];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

`applyChange` does not contains any UI manipulations, except deleteRowsAtIndexPaths/insertRowsAtIndexPaths/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths;
Debug output is `@([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) is 1`

Comment: Could you show where you call `endUpdates`, and what you do there?

Comment: Yes and No. Like I say, code Is pretty complex. There is self-written framework with pretty bad code and method swizzling instead of inheritance in it, partially rewrited by me. Table updating part is rewrited by me, but this issue already was there.

Comment: Post is updated, by the way,

Comment: I am afraid @Krypt, you've already answered your question.